# Java regex find last digit consecutively from 0-9 and first 6 digits are same

Tags: java, regex

I would like a regular expression in java that finds 
 - only first 6 digits are same
and
 - the last digit range from 0-9 consecutively.

1303250
1303251

1304150
1304151
1304152
1304153
1304154
1304155
1304156
1304157
1304158
1304159

In this case the expression will match 130415X.

I developed two separate regex as

```
        Pattern f6 = Pattern.compile("^......");
        Pattern last = Pattern.compile("\\d$");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, we write a regex to group the first 6 digits (followed by a 0), and check for that group followed by the count number up to 9.  We find matches in your string, and then print out that first grouping if a match is found.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String test = "1304150 1304151 1304152 1304153 1304154 1304155 1304156 1304157 1304158 1304159\r\n" +
                  "5304150 5304151 5304152 5304153 5304154 5304155 5304156 5304157 5304158 5304159\r\n" + 
                  "7304150 7304153 71304156";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{6})0 (?:\\1)1 (?:\\1)2 (?:\\1)3 (?:\\1)4 (?:\\1)5 (?:\\1)6 (?:\\1)7 (?:\\1)8 (?:\\1)9", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(new String(m.group(1)) + "X");
    }
 }
```

}

Output:

```
130415X
530415X
```

If it finds a match, it prints out the relevant 6 digits plus an "X".  [See it in action here](http://goo.gl/Ahhsr9).

[Regex explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%5Cd%7B6%7D%290+%28%3F%3A%5C1%291+%28%3F%3A%5C1%292+%28%3F%3A%5C1%293+%28%3F%3A%5C1%294+%28%3F%3A%5C1%295+%28%3F%3A%5C1%296+%28%3F%3A%5C1%297+%28%3F%3A%5C1%298+%28%3F%3A%5C1%299).  Essentially, it groups the first match of 6 digits which are followed by a 0.  Then, it looks for that group followed by a 1, that group followed by a 2, etc.  The double '\' throughout the string are just to escape the character in the Java string, and the regex should be read without the double slashes:

`(\d{6})0 (?:\1)1 (?:\1)2 (?:\1)3 (?:\1)4 (?:\1)5 (?:\1)6 (?:\1)7 (?:\1)8 (?:\1)9`

```
   NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    \d{6}                    digits (0-9) (6 times)
  )                        end of \1
  0                        '0 '
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
  )                        end of grouping
  1                        '1 '
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
  )                        end of grouping
  2                        '2 '
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
  )                        end of grouping
  3                        '3 '
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
  )                        end of grouping
  4                        '4 '
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
  )                        end of grouping
  5                        '5 '
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
  )                        end of grouping
  6                        '6 '
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
  )                        end of grouping
  7                        '7 '
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
  )                        end of grouping
  8                        '8 '
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
  )                        end of grouping
  9                        '9'
```

As requested in the comments, to do the opposite you can use:

`^(?!((\d{6})0 (?:\2)1 (?:\2)2 (?:\2)3 (?:\2)4 (?:\2)5 (?:\2)6 (?:\2)7 (?:\2)8 (?:\2)9)).*$`

As expected, inverse matches are a bit more complicated, but [here's the explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%28%3F%21%28%28%5Cd%7B6%7D%290+%28%3F%3A%5C2%291+%28%3F%3A%5C2%292+%28%3F%3A%5C2%293+%28%3F%3A%5C2%294+%28%3F%3A%5C2%295+%28%3F%3A%5C2%296+%28%3F%3A%5C2%297+%28%3F%3A%5C2%298+%28%3F%3A%5C2%299%29%29.*%24) and also you can [see it in action](http://goo.gl/za3eBa).

Comment: Could you explain the  regex?

Comment: Added an explanation :)

Comment: @Nick Bartlett, how do we develop an inverse match in this case?

Comment: Could you remove all the lines with hyphens so it doesn't take up quite so much vertical space? I don't think they're really necessary, except for maybe the top one.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes that should be better.  Also, inverse matches are more difficult, but for grabbing lines that don't match this pattern this should work: http://goo.gl/BNLJBu

Comment: @ColinZhong See Nick's comment just above this one.

Comment: @Nick Many thanks! ...How did you make that explanation, though? Was it a tool or did you do it manually?

Comment: @ColinZhong I used a tool to auto-generate the explanation: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl.  It adds the lines, to remove them I just used my editor.  https://regex101.com/ is pretty useful as well for creating, understanding, and testing regex matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d{6})0 (?:\1)1 (?:\1)2 (?:\1)3 (?:\1)4 (?:\1)5 (?:\1)6 (?:\1)7 (?:\1)8 (?:\1)9
```

(Double up on backslashes if you use it in Java's regexp constructor, as it accepts a string which will strip a level of backslashes.)